# How to Find and Replace HTML Tags attribute by using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, inline

I want to find and replace a tag attribute or change inline css by using Jquery.

For Example : `<span style="text-decoration: underline;">`

I want to find inline style`<span style="text-decoration: underline;">` and replace it to `<span class="line">` this on page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this DEMO : https://jsfiddle.net/yv5apdaj/

You can do like this, update the css style according to your need.

In this way, you still can use other styles and remove the desired css style only.

#### JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span').each(function(){
        if($(this).css('text-decoration') === 'underline'){
            $(this).css({'text-decoration':''});
            $(this).addClass('line');
        }    
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">Test Content</span><br /><br />
<span style="text-decoration: underline;">Test Content</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

On dom ready you can target all span elements like

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('span[style]').removeAttr('style')
})
```

If you want to target all elements with style attribute

```
$('[style]').removeAttr('style')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple in Jquery just use following,

```
 $("span").removeAttr("style");
 $("span").addClass("line");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('span[style]')
        .removeAttr('style')
        .addClass('line');
});
```

If you need to match the underline rule *exactly*, you can add a constraint. Just replace this:

```
$('span[style]')
```

with this:

```
$('span[style="text-decoration: underline;"]')
```

And just for completeness, here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8wwjk5k/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('span[style]').removeAttr('style').addClass("line")
})
```

This should do

Answer (score 0):

See [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nazexd7h/)

**Html**

```
<p>My mother has <span style="text-decoration: underline;">blue</span> eyes and my father has <span style="text-decoration: underline;">dark green</span> eyes.</p><button  onclick="btncheck();">Check</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
           $('span[style="text-decoration: underline;"]')
             .removeAttr('style')
             .addClass('line');
         });                  
   });
```